# Find the deletion date of a deleted Moodle course in the moodle database

Tags: moodle

Is there a way in Moodle or in the Moodle database to look up the date on which a certain course, e.g. "Mathematics 5a" was deleted?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the log table `mdl_logstore_standard_log`

If you don't know the course id, the course name is stored in the `other` column

```
SELECT timecreated
FROM mdl_logstore_standard_log
WHERE action = 'deleted'
AND target = 'course'
AND other LIKE '%Mathematics 5a%'
```

Or if you know the course id

```
AND courseid = 99
```